# How to commit the last un-commit action in git

Tags: git

Most of the previous threads are asking how to undo the last commit. But I was wondering if is possible to undo the last uncommit. I ran `git reset --hard HEAD^` but it didn't uncheckout all the files that were committed and now they are deleted.

How to commit the last un-commit action?

Comment: what is a uncommit action?

Comment: What do you mean by "uncheckout all the files"? Files are not checked out. Branches are. Please explain exactly what the results you saw, and how that differs from your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `git checkout - .` without resetting anything